# What is the proper way to read a text file and display in HTML via Flask/Python?

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

Specifically, let's talk about large text/log files that we want to display in HTML.  I've seen various methods, but for scalability purposes,

What I would like to do, is take a log file with space separated data and then put this into a table displayed in HTML.

Example from the text file:

```
2016-05-10 21:13:56.030616 Button_Pressed
2016-05-10 21:14:44.534093 Door_Opened
2016-05-10 21:14:46.850801 Button_Pressed
2016-05-10 21:15:04.383880 Door_Closed
```

I'd like to take each line and convert this to a table with headings "Date, Time, Event".

The easy way would be to use some kind of list, where we read each line into the list, then pass the list to the HTML on a return.

Example Python code excerpt from a Flask web app (app.py):

```
@app.route('/history')
def history():

    with open('events.log') as event_log:
    event_lines = event_log.readlines()

    door_history = []
    events = len(event_lines)

    for x in range(events):
        door_history.append(event_lines[x].split(" "))

    return render_template('door-log.html', events=events, door_history=door_history)
```

Example HTML/Jinja code excerpt from the Flask web app (door-log.html)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Event</th>
    </tr>

    {% for row in range(events) %}
        <tr>
            {% for column in range(3) %}
            <td> {{ door_history[row][column] }} </td>
            {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

However, for this method, would this not be the best use of memory?  Would it scale if you had many people accessing the same page?  Is this the proper way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: How large will your log file be? For very short logs this should be a workable solution. Also how many users do you want to access the page?

Comment: If the file is really big you wouldn't typically show it all in a single page anyway. You'd paginate the results, say 1000 lines per page.

Comment: @H2O This is for a home project and the log files are probably going to be relatively small (i.e. a month of activity on a garage door).  Probably never more than 2 users at a time.

Comment: @Alex Hall you're definitely right that the pagination solution would be a better option if the file is indeed that large.  I may go that route, thanks!

Comment: In general, I definitely going to use the above for my current project, but was academically curious if I was doing it correctly or if there were better more system friendly ways of handling it.  I think @H2O fully answered my question below so he/she gets the green check mark. :)

Comment: You don't need `range`. You can iterate over `event_lines`. `for line in event_lines:` You can further reduce this to a comprehension. `door_history = [line.split(' ') for line in event_log]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not say that your way is exactly the proper way of doing this. However for a small application it will work and be faster than most other solutions.

If your log file grows over time you would not want to show it in it's entirety. Instead you might want to implement only showing the latest 10 or so events, offering a second page with more events (pagination).
In this case you could probably still work with an adapted version of the above solution.

If however you either have lots of page views or want to have advanced features such as: showing the last week of events, just showing door opening events or showing all door opening events that happend in the first calendar week. Then you would want to make your data more accessible by importing it into some kind of database.

You might use SQLite as a database though if you really have a lot of users something like PostgreSQL would be the better option. You would not import the data in your views instead you would have a dedicated task running that updates your database every now an again. In the simplest case this might be a cronjob that just runs every minute. You might also use a more advanced solution like celery, in either case you might end up with slightly outdated data in your database and therefore your website, there isn't really a way around this.

For information on how to integrate a database into your application see the [official flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/). 
For more information on celery (for regular database updates) take a look at the [flask documentation on the topic](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/celery/). The slightly more hacky way to do this would be cron jobs, as explained [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto).

All that being said: if this is just a simple home project and you are not in for the learning experience your current solution will 100% suffice.
If you are interested in learing more or want lots of people to use

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly the kind of thorough response I was hoping for.  I'm just learning Python (and Flask) and this is definitely a big help in my journey.